# How to replace the Camunda Authentication with OAuth2 provider

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, camunda

I was trying to write OAuth2 plugin for Camunda , I followed the interface

> org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.identity.ReadOnlyIdentityProvider

and I followed the process for LDAP, to replace the auth and get user list from Oauth2 provider and also the groups.

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.7/user-guide/process-engine/identity-service/

Is there any implantation is there for Camunda OAuth2 ?

Comment: Hi vimal, were able to find an implementation ? Thank you

Comment: @lads no not able to find one, so created simple server

Answer (score 2):

Which Camunda deployment and which OAuth provider are you using?

Camunda offers an example for keycloak on GitHub:
https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-identity-keycloak
The implementation for your provider would likely look very similar.

Have not QAed this, but you might also find inspiration here:
https://github.com/hobbstech/camunda-spring-oauth2-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/io/github/hobbstech/camunda/oauth2/plugin